# How to download a .gz and use it as a command?

Tags: macos, command-line, tar

I recently had the need to install a command to limit cpu recources to a task. (If you're interested, the source is here: http://www.willnolan.com/cputhrottle/cputhrottle.html)

This task has always bewildered me and I've never understood through the internet. I downloaded the file 'cputhrottle.gz'

Unpacked it (I believe it's like a zip file)
then followed the instructions of:

'(You must run "chmod +x cputhrottle" after running "gunzip cputhrottle.gz", in order to make the program executable. Otherwise, it will not start correctly. Some folks have noted that gunzip says that the file is not in gzip format. In that case, try renaming the file to "cputhrottle" and running as-is. I confess I have no idea why this happens -- probably the browser or web server trying to be helpful but failing miserably.)'

And I'm left with an executable file. I'm not sure if this is where I'm meant to end up. How I then use this file as a command, I'm not sure!

Any help, and explanation of what this is would be greatly appreciated! Although, I'm not the most technical in this computer language at the age of 14, so go easy. :)

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct tags on the question? OSX != Linux

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info, changed 'Linux' tag to 'osx'. Would you like me to remove the edit?

Comment: Yes please. Remove the edit and add your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to get my head around this, I believe I have an answer.

The `.gz` file format is similar to the commonly used `.zip` or I've seen this be used more commonly.

After unpacking this by either double clicking and the `unarchiver` tool on the mac do the work or using the `gunzip` command in the console to achieve the same result:

```
gunzip cputhrottle.gz
```

After this you're left with a seemingly meaningless file in the finder, a blank page icon. This is the file the terminal uses to run the command.

To then run the command, change directory to where the `.gz` file has been extracted - most likely your downloads - in this case:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Run the `chmod` command to make the file executable

```
chmod +x cputhrottle
```

Now in the finder the icon will be have the words 'exec' in the icon meaning it's now executable. If you change directory to this file you can run it with the parameters.

Assuming you're already in the directory:

```
sudo cputhrottle [PID] [%CPU]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I recently had the need to install a command to limit cpu recources to a task

From the link you provided:

> cputhrottle is a small OS X command-line utility.

You won't be able to run it as it on Linux.

If you are able to build it on Linux, then the link also tells you how to run it: `sudo ./cputhrottle 328 25`

If you are running OSX you can use [nice](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nice.1.html) to "execute a utility with an altered scheduling priority"

---

#### What is a gz file and how do I open a gz file?

> > A GZ, or GNU Zipped Archive file is a compression utility developed by Jean-Loup Gailly and Mark Adler as a free software to replace
> >     Compress in early Unix systems. It allows for better compression and
> >     freedom from patented algorithms. GZ was adopted by the GNU Project,
> >     and is relatively popular on the Internet. GZIP produces files with a
> >     GZ extension, which can be decompressed by GUNZIP.
> >
> > By default, GZIP keeps the original file name as well as the time stamp in the compressed file. These are used when decompressing the
> >     file with the option -N. This is useful when a compressed file name
> >     was truncated or when the time stamp was not preserved after the file
> >     was transferred.
> >
> > A file or folder, or even a group of files and folders can be selected by a user and compressed as one GZ file. Multiple GZ files
> >     can even be compressed as one GZ file, or these GZ files can be placed
> >     by the folder that can then be compressed as a GZ file. The GZIP
> >     compression technology and the GZ compression format were developed
> >     for Linux systems, though there are certain Microsoft Windows
> >     decompression applications implemented with support for decompressing
> >     and opening these GZ files. Gzip is normally used to compress just a
> >     single file. Users of Mac platforms can also install and use some
> >     compatible Mac decompression tools to open and view the archived
> >     content of these GZ files.
> >
> > **How do I open a .GZ File?**
> >
> > In order to extract a .gz file you can use GZIP/GNUZIP program. It is a software application used for file compression. It is based on the
> >     DEFLATE algorithm, which is a combination of LZ77 and Huffman coding.
>
> Use the following command:
>
> ```
> $ gunzip file.gz
> ```

Source [What is a gz file and how do I open a gz file?](http://www.openthefile.net/extension/gz)

---

#### Why do I have to run `chmod + x`?

> You must run "chmod +x cputhrottle" after running "gunzip cputhrottle.gz

In order to execute a file on Unix it must have the correct permissions.

`chmod +x` sets the permissions so the the program can be e**X**ecuted.

See [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) for more information.

---

#### I'm left with an executable file. How I then use this file as a command?

You execute it by typing it's name. Unix will look into the `PATH` to try and find the command.

If it is in the current directory then the following will work:

```
./cputhrottle 328 25
```

Adding `sudo` before the command runs it as the superuser:

```
sudo ./cputhrottle 328 25
```

See [sudo](http://ss64.com/bash/sudo.html) for more information.

---

#### Restricting process CPU usage using nice, cpulimit, and cgroups

**nice**

> The nice command tweaks the priority level of a process so that it runs less frequently. This is useful when you need to run a CPU intensive task as a background or batch job. The niceness level ranges from -20 (most favorable scheduling) to 19 (least favorable). Processes on Linux are started with a niceness of 0 by default. The nice command (without any additional parameters) will start a process with a niceness of 10. At that level the scheduler will see it as a lower priority task and give it less CPU resources.

...

> What this means in real terms is that if you want to run a CPU intensive task you can start it using nice and the scheduler will always ensure that other tasks have priority over it. This means that the server (or desktop) will remain responsive even when under heavy load.
>
> Nice has an associated command called renice. It changes the niceness level of an already running process. To use it, find out the PID of process hogging all the CPU time (using ps) and then run renice:

...

**cpulimit**

> The cpulimit tool curbs the CPU usage of a process by pausing the process at different intervals to keep it under the defined ceiling. It does this by sending SIGSTOP and SIGCONT signals to the process. It does not change the nice value of the process, instead it monitors and controls the real-world CPU usage.
>
> cpulimit is useful when you want to ensure that a process doesn't use more than a certain portion of the CPU. The disadvantage over nice is that the process can't use all of the available CPU time when the system is idle.

Source [Restricting process CPU usage using nice, cpulimit, and cgroups](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups)

Comment: Helped, however, I asked what the .gz format is and what I do to get the command out of it (Unpacking then executing). I'd rather know what and how to do this then linking to other alternatives of the job I'd like to do.

Comment: It's a compressed archive file. Answer updated.

Comment: Answered my own question now, not used to this question and answer thing, hopefully I did it right, I'm not sure if there's a 'standard' you should follow.

Comment: @T.Hep Your answer looks OK. You might want to read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) which explains how to format your answer. For example it is good to use the correct formatting for code. I will fix it up for you and you will be able to see the difference.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll be sure to use it in any other answers I rarely come across! :)